# Do Battle Royale item spawns rely on location?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

I encountered somebody in voice chat who was talking about how different areas were good or bad for loot, so I wondered if there was any truth to that.

It seems that the loot chests randomly spawn in a set of predetermined spots and that there is a degree of randomness to what loot spawns in exact locations, but general areas seem to tend more towards specific items. For example, I seem to be able to reliably find a shotgun in the prison, not always in the exact same spot, but in another area different types of weapons might be more abundant. Additionally, I'll find that certain areas seem more likely to spawn more chests.

Am I just noticing coincidences, or is there any evidence that some areas tend to have different kinds of loot? If so, what are the patterns?

Comment: I noticed this with llamas near pleasant

Answer (score 2):

**Items will always spawn in the same spots.** They have a chance to spawn and they will be random every time.

Comment: Do you have anything to back this up?

Comment: There do appear to be a list of predetermined item spawn locations, but this doesn't really answer the question as to whether anything other than a random process determines what spawns in those locations.

Answer (score 0):

No the Fortnite Battle Royale items are all randomly spawned.  I've found blue's upon landing in the middle of nowhere as well as deep in buildings.  The idea of there being fixed location spawns for items kind of ruins the idea of how this mode should work.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that there are fixed spawns, but rather that some locations might be more likely to either spawn items of a certain variety or spawn a greater quantity of items.

Comment: @Zissouu No it wouldn't some areas can have a higher percentage of spawns/better spawns and it still be fine. See PU Battlegrounds as an example. I'm inclined to guess it's the same here

Comment: @Zissouu How did you quantify that? Did you measure and record it? I'm not saying your experience doesn't mean anything, but it's not really any different than me saying my experience suggests that there are differences. I also think that this wouldn't necessarily be a bad thing, as it could encourage different strategies (Do I take a big risk now by fighting over the top loot, or do I collect resources from calmer areas while the competition kills itself off?)

Comment: I'm with Broneironaut on this one. If one place had a "win button" weapon it might be broken but a variation in loot quality is fine. If 99 people go to that area then the one person who doesn't has an entire maps worth of loot to choose from with no competition. It actually makes for a better game because rather than always dropping as far away from other people as possible you have to decide whether your skills are up to scrambling for good loot in a corwded area or if you'd be better off choosing somewhere safer with less good loot. As LethalCoder says, this is how PUBG works.

Answer (score -1):

Floor loot is random and will spawn in the same spots. However, there is a chance to spawn nothing in that spot.

You can see [this](https://db.fortnitetracker.com/loot/floor#header_empty) post for a full list of what can spawn at floor loot and the chances.